# If the Rougarou flees after taking enough damage, do you add a doom token after the investigator phase?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

The third agenda card says to add a doom token when the rougarou isn’t engaged by the end of the investigation phase. Does this include when successfully damaging it and having it flee?

Comment: Could you add the scenario name please?

Comment: @LamaDelRay Since we haven't heard back I would assume [Curse of The Rougarou](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/209728/arkham-horror-card-game-curse-rougarou-scenario-pa)